# Using ADO.NET Linq to Sql and Entity Data Model in same Project causes Naming instances errors

Tags: linq-to-sql, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using ADO.NET LinqtoSql for populating data into SqlDatabase tables after parsing from flat files using LINQ. I am also using an Entity Data Model in the same project for displaying those Populated SqlDatabase tables in a JQGrid.

Entity Data Model is used to select datasets from multiple columns from multiple SqlDatabase tables using LINQ.

Exceptions and Errors obtained:

```
Ambiguity between 'TABLE.TABLEONE.FileCreated' and 'TABLE.TABLEONE.FileCreated' 

The type 'TABLE.TABLEONE' already contains a definition for 'Tableone_ID'
```

I am able to rectify these errors if the definitions declared in the ADO.NET Entity Model.edmx design are renamed to a different name.

How to resolve the exceptions without changing the definitions and proceed with our development. Help needed.

Comment: It's impossible to help if we don't see the code that throws the exceptions. I think EF and linq-to-sql generated the same class names.

Comment: @GertArnold: Edited with sample code as requested.

Comment: Did you check the class names? You have to rename one of them.

Comment: @GertArnold : The DBML also generates TABLETWO class name in LINQ and EDMX also generates TABLETWO in autogenerated file. Both referrring to same tables in DB Design.

Comment: @GertArnold +1 for changing class names. I changed the class names in my DBML design. It worked.

Comment: @GertArnold : could you please help me on this question too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469282/dynamically-generated-dropdownlist-web-controls-hides-on-selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the conflicts of the definitions and ambiguity between `DBML` and `EDMX` design. Renamed the class names of `DBML` as `TABLEONE_DBML` and it worked well for `EDMX`.